# jQuery: div field won't move

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move a div down when a button is clicked and a new div appears above it (basically a new div should push the other div down and show)

I've tried 'top' and 'bottom' with different pxes, the animation works but it just doesn't push the other div down and instead appears under it (things get messy there)

this is my code for the animation part:

```
            $('#button').click(function() {
            $('#textfield').show('fast')
            $('#divfield').show().animate({ 'bottom': 300 }, 1000);
            });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) and replicate the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSFIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/CQx8W/

**JS**

```
$('#textfield').hide();
$('#button').click(function() {
        $('#textfield').show('fast')
        $('#divfield').show().animate({ 'bottom': 300 }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: ah yes, thank you this worked! will accept this answer when the time is in :)

Comment: had to wait a few mins before I can click accept (it's silly)

Comment: umm can I use if statements to show the textfield div again when clicked (like toggle) (if, else)?

Comment: Yes. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/CQx8W/1/ - Don't use if, toggle does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textfield').hide();
```

afterwards you can use

```
$('#textfield').show();
```

to show something , it has to be hidden , so you have to hide your text div !!